# multiple fragments on single activity

Tags: android, fragment

I am new to Android. I need some information about fragment. Can I create heavy network tasks on fragment that create on activity?

Please tell me if I can create heavy tasks on fragment ANR occur on Activity?

Answer (score 0):

> I am new in Android I need some information about fragment. I need your help please.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/guide/components/fragments.html) you have info about fragments in android. And yes, you can create multiple fragment on you activity, is the method to have various activitys in a single one

Comment: if fragment destroy then activity also destroy??

Comment: I create Navigation drawer and I use fragments on Main Activity. I craete network connection. If connection may take some time on network connection and downloding Json text then activity has affected or not??

Comment: Please, read the tutorial that i have passed you. In which way you mean affected? If the download takes 10 secs, then your acitivity will wait 10 secs.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I create heavy network tasks on fragment that create on activity?

No, because you cannot run any networking on UI thread (that would result in the Exception) but also "yes" because you can have your "heavy networking" AsyncTask  started internally by Fragment.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I use fragment instead of Activity. it works like activity for network task with Handler or Asynstask?

Comment: Yes, because by default all code runs on UI thread. So Fragment or Activity - makes no difference. You must spawn AsyncTask or IntentService for networking or heavy computations